# Post Request on PhoneGap does not work

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I'm building an Android App using PhoneGap with AngularJS.

**For Reaching the server side i'm using the $http service of AngularJS**

Evrything works fine when reaching the server side with GET methods.

Once using POST, it seems like the request never leaves de app. 
The same process on a browser page works perfectly.

here is my POST request

```
$http.post(URL_REQUEST,data,{'headers':{'Content-Type':'application/json' }})
.success(function(d, status, headers, config, statusText) {
    console.log("  success");

}).error(function(d, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("  error");
});
```

And in my logcat i get this as a error result :

```
"status":403,
"config":{"method":"POST",
"transformRequest":[null],
"transformResponse":[null], 
...
```

Again on the broswer evrything works perfectly. On the PhoneGap App only GET request works

Comment: 403 is forbidden. Are you able to log the HTTP request on the server? If so, I would compare the POST sent from phonegap app to the one sent from the browser, and then you can tell.

Comment: Hi, did that with no success. the request is not reaching the filters at all. I'm using genymotion for the emulator by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it from this post :

[Cordova POST - Request Forbidden 403. Not reaching Dispatcher Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973290/cordova-post-request-forbidden-403-not-reaching-dispatcher-servlet)

Seems like phonegap have a problem when having CORSFilter on the Web.xml file. Dont know why. but once removed it works

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Cordova 5 you may need to configure your [Content Security Policy](http://content-security-policy.com/) meta tag in your index.html document to allow content to be fetched from other servers.  You can specify this per server host, or wildcard.  By default it's turned off, so that you have to think about security and what you want to enable.

Here's an example that allows access to one domain (api.mydomain.com):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://api.mydomain.com">
```

You could wildcard this if you wanted access to everywhere.

Comment: I'm using Cordova 5.1.1 with GenyMotion for the emulator.

Comment: i have wildcare the connect-src but still have this problem. while all get request work fine, the post ones dont even reach the container filter.  did anyone have success with post request on genymotion?

Comment: i'm trying to connect to my localhost wich in genymotion is http://10.0.3.2:8080 , once again the GET request works fine. but the post ones are blocked and throw error immediately with a 403 FORBIDEN code