# Cordova Android App can't post 403 Forbidden

Tags: cordova, http-status-code-403

I have a Java REST Service which takes post request. My Cordova packaged as Android App cannot make a post request.

I get a 403 Forbidden error. I know many people have given many suggestions. I've tried all of those but still can't solve. Any help will help greatly.

My Cordova config file looks like this.

```
<content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />    
    <access origin="*" />
<access uri="*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

I tried removing         based on suggestion from someone. But still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use cookies in Ajax?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    data = {name:'name'},
    url = 'https://example.com';
request.setRequestHeader("cookieItem1", "cookieContent1");
request.setRequestHeader("cookieItem2", "cookieContent2");
request.open("POST", url);
request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

I tried this to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes across this. The problem maybe due to a CORS issue. Usually http calls from within a cordova app have the **origin=file://** header set. Some web server may have a security filter to prevent security attacks.

The easiest will be to make sure the server that you are doing the http request do not block them if the **origin** header has the **file://** value. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24976158/3792636)

Otherwise you will need to find a way to change the header to something else before making the request.