# Wakanda error when I use method on device or emulator

Tags: wakanda

I use a server method in my project, when I run in preview mode and get a preview of my project on a web browser, I have the expected result. However, when I run it on emulator or device I have the following error message: 
"POST http://192.168.1.247:8108/rest/SuperHero/myMethod 403 (Forbidden)".

Do you know why I have this error? What is the cause of this? How can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you get 403 error with GET request? Looks like it might relate to CORDOVA's configuration.  You might have to configure CORDOVA to allow access to 192.168.1.247:8108, or set up CORS in Wakanda.  Reference: [Post Request on PhoneGap does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973290/cordova-post-request-forbidden-403-not-reaching-dispatcher-servlet)

Comment: thank you for the answer. In the config.xml I have this line : 
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.247:8108"/> so I think its ok, so I setup CORS in Wakanda to allow access to 192.168.1.247:8102. I can access my data via rest. But I still have this error message.

Comment: Access data via REST typically uses GET instead of POST. Can you test updating your data using [$method=update](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/HTTP-REST/Manipulating-Data/methodupdate.303-815150.en.html) POST request? If it does not work, it could mean that the server does not allow POST request.